# How to restrict access to an application based on Location?

Tags: java, node.js, reactjs, spring-boot, devops

Can we restrict the particular flow of the User Interface based on location (***Location-Based Access Control***)?

One part of the User Interface and its functionalities should only be available only when the User is, in particular, geographical location? We planned with **Whitelisting IP address based on network**, but due to the lack of the network infrastructure and over-head cost for the same. We concluded that Network**-based restriction** cannot be a valid solution.

We also looked into GPS based solution, where we cannot rely on the browser application to get an appropriate location.

If anyone of you has worked on similar technology previously, please let us know how did you deal with the problem?

Comment: I'm no expert on this but I'll try: IP addresses can be spoofed and the assignment to a geographical local might change and not be up-to-date. Without any additional tools I'd say that GPS and maybe in conjunction with network based location seems to be the best option. If you can use additional tools like beacons you could try and require proximity to a certain beacon to make the flow available.

Answer (score 1):

A general solution would be to get user location coordinates via some API, then compare it with your list of allowed coordinates. If the coordinates are within the range of your list, then you will start the Activity such that it loads the proper View. Otherwise, you load another View informing user that they have been denied access.
Note that this method is readily susceptible to exploit unless backed up by some other strong handling API.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a database Resources table which can contain name of resources a user can access according to their geolocation. On page load you can query if user has access to the page [you can also create a request filter using spring security] and redirect accordingly. To get geolocation using an IP address you can use `geoIp2` . You can follow the [Geolocation by IP in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/geolocation-by-ip-with-maxmind) Tutorial.

And as for resource table data its preferable that it contains data of geolocation for which resources are blocked.

And you can get client IP address using Java or you can use JavaScript.

> [How to get client Ip Address in Java](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-java/)

And probably you should save request IP address for audit for the resources dependent on geolocation.

Comment: The problem with GeoIP is that it can easily be spoofed, right? It won't always show the right location. I have spoofed it myself and tested this approach.

Comment: the thing is the only way you can get exact location is if user willingly provides access. And the user will most likely deny your location access if your app is not completely dependent on it like Uber or delivery hero. If you are looking to bypass user vpn then you should connect with networking department. even if possible its too much work for too little gain. even YouTube if blocked in a country can be accessed by vpn.